# Matrix Multiplication for loop of n number of months

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a matrix multiplication problem in a chain format. 
I only have a input Matrix A, will save Matrix B <- Matrix A. 
Need to multiply in the below fashion

```
A * B = C
B * C = D
C * D = E
D * E = F
```

this chain of multiplication taken places till 18 months. 
i have tried the below code: but not able to select which loop i should go for.

Matrix A:

```
2   3
4   2
```

Code:

```
a = matrix( c(2, 3, 4, 2), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE) 
a

b <- a
b

c = b %*% a
c

d <- c %*% b
d

e <- d %*% c
e
```

i am doing this multiplication manually till, i want to do it in chain loop fashion for 18 times.

Expected output:

> a

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    3
[2,]    4    2
```

> b

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    3
[2,]    4    2
```

> c = b %*% a
>
> c

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]   16   12
[2,]   16   16
```

> d <- c %*% b
>
> d

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   80   72
[2,]   96   80
```

> e <- d %*% c
>
> e

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 2432 2112
[2,] 2816 2432
```

so this should be repeated for 18 times. Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: HOw about `Reduce('%*%', mget(letters[1:5]), accumulate = TRUE)`

Comment: Do you need directly the answer after 18 times or you would also need the middle steps as matrices?

Comment: @akrun i tried with your code: i only sure about the letter A and B, hence this is not working. it should be in loop.

Comment: @Ronak, direct answers of all multiplications. that means 18 matrices.

Comment: You may need `c <- d <-e <- matrix(1, 2, 2)`

Comment: @akrun - not sure how this will work.

Comment: `for(i in seq(17)) {
  c = b %*% a;
  a = b;
  b = c;
  print(b);
} 
`

Comment: @RonakShah thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplication results in `Inf` from 12th loop onward as the value become too large to be stored in R.

Following code will store the value in list matmull. Its first 2 elements are original value A and B. from 3rd element onward it has results of multiplications in the loop

```
A <- matrix(c(2L, 4L, 3L, 2L), 2, 2)
matmull <- rep(list(A), 20)
for(i in 1:18){
 matmull[[i+2]] <- matmull[[i]]%*%matmull[[i+1]]
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the help and explanation.

Comment: 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L are the larger values when the matrix is small. But when the matrix is some where more than 12*12 or 18*18, and when reading that matrix from a .csv then it will create a problem. Is there any generic code to handle this case.

Comment: I did not get your point but i am assuming that you are writing 2L, 4L, 3L,2L in the csv file and then trying to read it. 2L, 4L... forms are way to tell R that these are integers and hence will use less memory than numeric. you can instead use 2, 4, 3, 2 and it will work just fine. In csv you should write as 2, 4, 3, 2 read.csv will be read them as numeric by default.

Answer (score 1):

A for loop will help here

```
matA <- matrix(c(2,4,3,2), ncol=2,nrow=2)
output_var<- array(dim=c(2,2,18))
output_var[,,c(1:2)] <- matA
for (i in c(3:18))
{
  output_var[,,i] <- output_var[,,(i-1)]%*% output_var[,,(i-2)]
}
output_var
```

Comment: I am assuming you want to store and use (intermediate) values obtained for each of the months.

Comment: Thankyou Ganesh for your help.