# Matrix Multiplication using loop

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a matrix multiplication problem in a chain format. I only have a input Matrix A, will save Matrix B <- Matrix A. Need to multiply in the below fashion

```
C = B * A
D = C * A
E = D * A
```

A is a reference matrix for all the multiplication for each month. 
this chain of multiplication taken places till 18 months.

Matrix A:

```
2   3
4   2
```

Code:

```
a = matrix( c(2, 3, 4, 2), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE) 
b <- a 
c <- b %*% a
d <- c %*% a
e <- d %*% a
f <- e %*% a
g <- f %*% a
```

Each time A is the reference matrix for future multiplication with the result. This repeated for 18 times.

I have to manually right the above multiplication for 18 times, so looking for a loop.

Expected Output:

> c <- b %*% a
>
> c

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   16   12
[2,]   16   16
```

> d <- c %*% a
>
> d

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   80   72
[2,]   96   80
```

> e <- d %*% a
>
> e

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  448  384
[2,]  512  448
```

> f <- e %*% a
>
> f

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 2432 2112
[2,] 2816 2432
```

so this should be repeated for 18 times. Please help. Thanks in Advance.

the logic is different in the earlier question posted.

Comment: Do you need all matrices or only the last result? You can write your own function for this task.

Comment: all the 18 matrices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix Multiplication for loop of n number of months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765860/matrix-multiplication-for-loop-of-n-number-of-months)

Comment: there are some changes in the multiplication of matrix. logic is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
Mpow <- function(A, n) {
  if (n==1) return(list(A))
  L <- list(A)
  P <- A
  for (i in 2:n) {
    P <- P %*% A
    L[[i]] <- P
  }
  return(L)
}

a = matrix( c(2, 3, 4, 2), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE) 
Mpow(a, 1)
Mpow(a, 2)
Mpow(a, 18)
```

You will get a list of the powers of the matrix. The matrix `f` in the question is the last element of `Mpow(a,5)`.
Here is short variant of the function:

```
Mpow <- function(A, n) {
  L <- list(A)
  if (n==1) return(L)
  P <- A
  for (i in 2:n) L[[i]] <- (P <- P %*% A)
  return(L)
}
```

Without defining a new function you can do:

```
n <- 5
Reduce('%*%', rep(list(a), n), accumulate=TRUE)
```